# Emacs equivalent of the following vim operation

Tags: commands, c

In the answer to a question on Quora, Gilles Castel wrote an answer highlighting the power of vim. 
The Question was:

> How would you write a C program to print 1 to 100 without loop, recursion, or goto?

[Here is the link to his Answer](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-write-a-C-program-to-print-1-to-100-without-loop-recursion-or-goto/answer/Gilles-Castel-1?srid=dNMP)

How would one go about implementing the same in Emacs?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do? What's the real question or use case? How will this question and its answer help Emacs users, including Emacs-Lisp programmers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emacs has keyboard macros with counter support. The gist of the solution would be (assuming default key bindings):

- `F3` to start recording a macro
- Type `printf("%d", "`
- `F3` to insert the macro counter
- Type the rest of the line, `");`
- `F4` to end recording the macro
- Use `F4` with a prefix to run the macro n times, e.g. `C-u 1 0 0 F4`.

If you want to play editor golf and compare with that vim solution, I think the equivalent sequence would be this:

```
#include <stdio.h><RET>
int main(){<RET>
<F3>printf("%d ", <F3>);<RET>
<F4><C-p><C-S-backspace><C-u>100<F4>return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main() { puts ("1 to 100"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `tiny-expand` from the package `tiny` on ELPA.

Enter the following text and call the command (I like to bind it to <kbd>C-o</kbd>):

```
m1\n10|printf ("%%d ", %d);
```

The resulting buffer contents:

```
printf ("%d ", 1);
printf ("%d ", 2);
printf ("%d ", 3);
printf ("%d ", 4);
printf ("%d ", 5);
printf ("%d ", 6);
printf ("%d ", 7);
printf ("%d ", 8);
printf ("%d ", 9);
printf ("%d ", 10);
```